# Unity WebGL My Mobile Device Doesn't Tilt

Tags: mobile, unity-webgl

I'm creating a Unity 2D game which will be available on browser. In the game, I want to control my character with mobile device's tilt.

Unfortunately, my spaceship doesn't move even if I tilt my screen. However, it is working as Android app

Here is my code:

```
void Start()
    {
        float shipWidth = transform.localScale.x;
        float screenHalfWidth = Camera.main.aspect * Camera.main.orthographicSize;

        minX = -screenHalfWidth + (shipWidth * 6 / 11);
        maxX = screenHalfWidth - (shipWidth * 6 / 11);

        initialRotation = transform.rotation;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.acceleration.x;
        Move(horizontalInput);

        if (Time.time >= nextFireTime && Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Fire();
            nextFireTime = Time.time + 1f / fireRate;
        }
    }

    void Move(float horizontalInput)
    {
        float newXPosition = transform.position.x + horizontalInput * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        newXPosition = Mathf.Clamp(newXPosition, minX, maxX);

   
        float tiltAngle = -horizontalInput * tiltAmount;
        Quaternion targetRotation = initialRotation * Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, tiltAngle);

        transform.position = new Vector3(newXPosition, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, 0.5f);
    }
```

Can you guys help me with that?

I tried various solutions but nevertheless I couldn't find the right solution.